# When are readers/writers/streams identified as being open?

Tags: java, stream, writer, reader

I am creating an abstract binding class for a `Reader` and `Writer` where the user doesn't have to reference each one individually.

Example: I have a `FileStream` which inside of it houses both a `FileReader` and `FileWriter`.

The question I have refers to optimizing the class. I know I can't have two streams opened simultaneously due to concurrency, however I need to initialize them somewhere without having data leaks all over the place.

Are streams/readers/writers classified as being open, as soon as you initialize them, or are the 'pipes' only opened once the first read/write begins? I'm looking at the JavaDoc and don't see anything here about when the streams actually open up...

For those who do not understand what I am asking (ignoring try-catch blocks):

```
// does my reader become OPEN here?
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("foobar.txt"));

// or here, now that I have performed the first operation.
br.readLine();
```

Comment: both implement `Closeable` so if used in a `try-with` will be auto-closeable see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: _"I know I can't have two streams opened simultaneously due to concurrency"_ -- what do you mean by this? Do you mean input and output on the same file? _"without having data leaks all over the place"_ -- Why do you think this will occur? Please show some actual code and explain an actual problem.  As it stands your question seems to be based on some misconceptions, and is too abstract to be answered.

Comment: @JimGarrison I don't have examples, however I am doing this on a single thread which will cause synchronization issues if done at the same time. No use writing to a file and then attempting to read when the buffers are looking at different things. My question does not reference a clear problem but rather the abstract nature of (three) classes and therefore yes, I am writing an abstract question. It is however not ambiguous and I am sure that an answer is ***more than likely*** to be able to be answered.

Comment: Still interesting question; my vote for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are open as soon as you construct them. There is no 'open' operation, so they are already open.

Discussion:

`new FileInputStream(...)` and `new FileOutputStream(...)` open the file, as they throw `IOExceptions` about it. Practically every other input or output stream extends `FilterInput/OutputStream,` with a `FileInput/OutputStream` as its delegate (including socket input/output streams as a matter of fact). The `FileInput/OutputStream` is created first in any such stack, *ergo* it is already open before the decorator streams, *ergo* they are already open too.

`ByteArrayInput/OutputStreams` and `StringReader/Writer` don't need opening at all.

Comment: Then that's good to know. Simple and straightforward answer; thanyou! +1

Comment: I agree; although I think a tiny piece of additional information/explanation would help. As of now, the only thing that makes this thing a "credible answer" is context knowledge (as in "when EJP claims something, it is usually spot on").

Comment: @GhostCat That's all very well, but 'additional information/explanation' such as what? It's immediately apparent. There is no 'open' operation, so they are already open. QED. I'm not aware of any statement in the Javadoc that says so, but there doesn't need to be.

Comment: @EJP Well, in a "lazy" world, "nothing" might happen until a first read/write request. I agree with your assessment; I had just hoped there is a nice, precise JLS / javadoc to back that up.

Comment: @GhostCat No. Just reasoning. `new FileInputStream(...)` and `new FileOutputStream(...)` must open the file, as they throw `IOExceptions` about it. Practically every other input or output stream extends `FilterInput/OutputStream`, with a `FileInput/OutputStream` as its delegate (including socket input/output streams as a matter of fact). The `FileInput/OutputStream` is created first in any such stack, *ergo* it is already open before the decorator streams, *ergo* they are already open too. `ByteArrayInput/OutputStreams` and `StringReader/Writer` don't need opening at all.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution: forget about re-inventing the wheel.

Java has a class that is specifically designed to allow for reading and writing to the same file: [java.io.RandomAcessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html)

So, if you have to wrap around... Use that class, instead of combining two other things that were never intended to be combined!

Comment: Thankyou for acknowledging `RandomAccessFile` however I am creating **abstract** classes, that can be used for any type of Writer/Reader. Files, bytes, etc.

Comment: Oh, pardon me! Of course you can have my upvote. Your answer is of assuring quality. :)